# Calling actionresult from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my ActionResult()

```
    public ActionResult pay()
    {
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult mytry()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and this is my view pay.chtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("mytry", "Home"))
{ 
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="center">


        <input type="button" value="submit" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
}
```

I am not able to call the mytry() action result from here. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to submit your form, you must use `<input type="submit" />` or `<button type="submit">` Try the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("mytry", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
}
```

Comment: The type of the button should be (submit)

Comment: Glad it helped :) do not forget to check the answer as accepted :)